# cannot update entities using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I am trying to update an entity using following code.

```
 MemberFee originalMemberFee = db.MemberFees.FirstOrDefault(ann => ann.MemberId == memberFeeViewModel.MemberId && ann.Year == memberFeeViewModel.Year);

  if (originalMemberFee == null)
  {
        db.MemberFees.Add(memberFeeViewModel);
  }
  else
  {
       db.MemberFees.Attach(memberFeeViewModel);
       db.Entry(memberFeeViewModel).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
  }
  db.SaveChanges();
```

It creates the entity (inside the if-sats) successfuly however it genereates this error when it tries to update an entity
`Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the `memberFeeViewModel` key(s) is not properly set.

Check your `MemberId` and `Year` value of `memberFeeViewModel` object. If those are empty then you need to provide the keys before updating.

Comment: @user217648, What is the primary key(s) of memberFeeViewModel? and what is their value(s) ?

Comment: primary keys are integers; [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int MemberFeeId { get; set; }

MemberId is not primary key

Comment: @user217648, then you should check whether the `MemberFeeId` value when updating, whether the value exists in the database